# Max Dot Product of Two Subsequences

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Given two arrays nums1 and nums2.

Return the maximum dot product between non-empty subsequences of nums1 and nums2 with the same length.

A subsequence of a array is a new array which is formed from the original array by deleting some (can be none) of the characters without disturbing the relative positions of the remaining characters. (ie, [2,3,5] is a subsequence of [1,2,3,4,5] while [1,5,3] is not).

I was trying to solve this problem without using dp(dynamic programming)  , and reached to a point where certain cases were right but many other were wrong .

Can i make improvement in this approach or i will have to use dp.

```
class Solution {
public:
   
    int maxDotProduct(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        int n1 = nums1.size();
        int n2 =  nums2.size();
        int max , sum = 0 , count =0 ;
       if(n1>n2){
           for(int i=0;i<n2;i++){
                max = nums1[i]*nums2[i];
               count =0;
               for(int j=i+1;j<n1-n2 + count  ; j++){
                   if(nums1[j]*nums2[i]>max){
                       max = nums1[j]*nums2[i];
                   }
               }
               sum = sum + max;
               count ++;
           }}
           else{
                for(int i=0;i<n1;i++){
                    max = nums1[i]*nums2[i]; 
                    count =0;
               for(int j=i+1 ; j<n2-n1+count ; j++){
                   if(nums1[i]*nums2[j]>max){
                       max = nums1[i]*nums2[j];
                   }
               }
               sum = sum + max;
                    count++;
               
           }
               
           }
       return sum;
    }
};
```

Input:
[3,-2]
[2,-6,7]
Output:
18
Expected:
21